# how to send a get request with a string parameter containing '/' in angular 4 service?

Tags: angular, url, parameters, httpservice

I'm using angular 4 and http services and I want to call a service and pass a string to return a JSON value. my string is '97/422/1883' and my service code is :

```
getIncomingRelatedById(number) {
this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
return this.http.get(this.domain + '/mail/getIncomingRelatedById/' + number, this.options).map(res => res.json());
```

}
but when i run the code, i get the error below:

```
http://localhost:3000/mail/getIncomingRelatedById/97/422/1883 404 (Not Found)
```

how can i send my request now?

**update:**

and in the server side I have this :

```
    router.get('/getRelatedById/:id', (req, res) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: err
        });
      } else {
        client.query('select * from get_related_mail($1)', [req.params.id], 
         (err, mail) => {
          done();
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({
              success: false,
              message: err
            });
          } else {
          res.json({
            success: true,
            mail: mail,
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: How are you retrieving it on service side?

Comment: @Esco if you mean the server side, I edited my post!

Comment: I'll replace the "/" by "-". mystring = mystring.replace(/\//g, "-");

Comment: @Eliseo it's working! great idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think this link its helpful 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

this like has all characters and the values

for your problem this your character
**`'/'==>'%2F'`**